# How to handle one image source for two different transformation

Tags: android, android-glide

Little Background:
I'm building a media player app and i want my app to look something similar to the picture below.

[image: app]

As you can see, the same image goes background and at the same time it also appears in circled image view.

My first approach was to make two different `GlideApp` calls.

```
    GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.hunting_party)
            .transforms(
                    new CenterCrop(),
                    new BlurTransformation(60),
                    new ColorFilterTransformation(Color.parseColor("#b3808080"))
            )
            .into(mMainBackground);

    GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.hunting_party)
            .into(mAlbumArt);
```

However, I want to reuse prior `GlideApp` call so that it may work something like below.

```
GlideApp.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.hunting_party)
                .transforms(
                        new CenterCrop(),
                        new BlurTransformation(60),
                        new ColorFilterTransformation(Color.parseColor("#b3808080"))
                )
                .into(mMainBackground)
                // now remove prior transformation
                // and load into different view
                .into(mAlbumArt);
```

Any suggestion would be helpful!

*** Based on Vishal's code ***

In order for `RequestBuilder` to accept `transforms`, you should use `RequestOptions` instead.

```
RequestBuilder<Drawable> glideRequestBuilder = GlideApp.with(this).load(R.drawable.hunting_party);
        RequestOptions backgroundTransformOptions = new RequestOptions()
                .transforms(
                        new CenterCrop(),
                        new BlurTransformation(60),
                        new ColorFilterTransformation(Color.parseColor("#b3808080"))
                );

        glideRequestBuilder
                .into(mAlbumArt);

        glideRequestBuilder
                .apply(backgroundTransformOptions)
                .into(mMainBackground);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder

RequestBuilder<Drawable> glideRequestBuilder = GlideApp.with(this).load(R.drawable.hunting_party);

glideRequestBuilder.transforms(
                        new CenterCrop(),
                        new BlurTransformation(60),
                        new ColorFilterTransformation(Color.parseColor("#b3808080"))
                )
                .into(mMainBackground);
glideRequestBuilder.into(mAlbumArt);
```